# Git - How to generate a commit from git diff

Tags: git, version-control, git-diff

I am in `main` branch and there are some mismatches in `main` and `dev`. I can see the diff in a specific folder using,

```
git diff main..dev Code/Folder/*
```

Now I want to move all the changes the diff showing inside the **Code/Folder/*** into a new commit in current branch, main.

How do I do that?

Comment: Try `git diff main.dev Code/Folder/* | git apply` and then `git add <files> && git commit`.

Comment: If you want to apply the difference between main and dev, **to main**, then won't this produce the exact same file(s) as just grabbing a copy of the relevant files from dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code works fine (adding changes into main from dev),

```
git checkout main
git diff main..dev Code/Folder/* | git apply
git add *
git commit -s -m "Adding diffs to main from dev for Code/Folder/*"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, if possible, you could accept your solution as the answer, so it could also help other community members. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`git checkout <branch> <path>`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified#_with_paths) form like:

```
git checkout main
git checkout dev Code/Folder
# ... you may fix unwanted changes here ...
git commit -m "import Code/Folder from dev branch"
```

It will overwrite `<path>` with `<branch>`'s content without switching current branch.